# How to rectify error when the app is uninstalled and then reinstalled and goes to the home page

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication

If I uninstalls the app and then reinstall my app then it directly goes to the home page of the app. It doesn't ask the user to login.

I wrote the `authStateListener` for the current user to monitor when the app is removed in the background and then reinstalled, the app will show the login page instead of the Home page. When the user logs out then the app shows the login page otherwise the app goes to the home page. So when the user is logged out from the app and then uninstalls and reinstalls the app, it works correctly.

But my problem is if user isn't logged out, and uninstalls and reinstalls the app then it shows the home page of the app instead of the log in page. How do I solve this?

The code is :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var db : Firestore!
    var handle:AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    @IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var pswd: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         db=Firestore.firestore()

        print(currentReachabilityStatus != .notReachable)
        let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
        let authid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        print("token\(String(describing: token))")
        let docRef = self.db.collection("deyaPayUsers").document(authid!)
        docRef.setData(["FCMToken":token as Any],options:SetOptions.merge())

        self.handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
            if user != nil {
                if (user?.isEmailVerified)!{



                    let myVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "deyaPay") as!deyaPay
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(myVC, animated:true)



                }

                else{
                    let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Sorry. Your email address has not yet been verified. Do you want us to send another verification email to \(String(describing: self.email.text!)).", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let alertActionCancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)
                    //alertVC.addAction(alertActionOkay)
                    alertVC.addAction(alertActionCancel)
                    self.present(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }

    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if currentReachabilityStatus != .notReachable
        {
            print("Connected")
        }
        else
        {
            let controller = UIAlertController(title: "No Internet Detected", message: "This app requires an Internet connection", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
            let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

            controller.addAction(ok)
            controller.addAction(cancel)

            present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener{ auth, user in
            if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {

                let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "deyaPay")as!deyaPay
                //self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
                let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
                self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                print("signout")
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Make a check to see if it is the first run and case positive delete the app settings

Comment: Please only show _relevant_ code in your question - don't just paste a whole file. e.g. why include `didReceiveMemoryWarning()`?